# How can I draw on an html canvas using Scala-JS

Tags: scala, canvas, scala.js

How can I obtain a canvas element and draw stuff on it?

Comment: Which version are you using? Did you import `dom._`? http://scala-js.github.io/scala-js-dom/#dom.HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: I'm using scala-js version 0.6.8. org.scalajs.dom.HTMLCanvasElement does not exist. Apparently the code I found was from an old version or something. I got the example you linked to working with dom.html.Canvas. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems you didn't use the latest version. You can find a working example here: http://scala-js.github.io/scala-js-dom/#dom.HTMLCanvasElement